# Why do I need to use a Postman pre-request for variables to work in the request body?

Tags: api, postman

In Postman 7.13.0 on Ubuntu, I have variables in one of my collections.  They are defined at collection level, not global level, and work perfectly everywhere except in the request body of my POST requests.  For example:

`"{{name}}"` in the request body ends up as `""` (the variable is not being substituted).  This throws 500 errors from my API as it is expecting a value to be passed.  The request I'm looking at is within the same collection that has the variable.

However, if I use a pre-request script like the following, the collection variables work as expected.

```
var vm_name = pm.variables.get("vm_name");
var cluster_uuid = pm.variables.get("cluster_uuid");
var cluster_name = pm.variables.get("cluster_name");

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("vm_name", vm_name)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cluster_name", cluster_name)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cluster_uuid", cluster_uuid)
```

Also, when creating the request body, typing `{{` does not begin the autocomplete sequence I'm used to seeing when using the variables elsewhere.  This suggests a scope issue although I'm sure that's being done correctly.

I've looked at the [Postman docs](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/) and I'm sure the scope is correct.

What am I doing wrong that means I must use a pre-request script?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an image of an example, please? Is `name` the variable you're using in the body? Is that the same name as the stored Collection variable key?

Comment: hi @DannyDainton - sorry for the delay in response (was on holiday).  Here's a partial post body that I'm using:

`{"spec":{ "name": "{{name}}",`.  `name` is one of the collection variables but doesn't work unless I do what I outlined above, i.e. specify the value in a pre-request script.

Yep, the variable is the same name as the stored Collection variable key.